# How to reconcile compiled scss and css isolation in a Blazor WASM application?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the following solution setup:

```
-MyProjectSolution
|-MyProjectWASM
|-MyProjectAPI
|-MyProjectDatabase
|-MyProjectStyle
|--|-[]BootstrapSourceFolder
   |--compilerconfig.json
   |--compilerconfig.json.defaults
   |--style.scss
```

The `MyProjectStyle` Project contains the downloaded source code from bootstrap, which gets importet in `style.css` and I am using *[Web Compiler 2022+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64)* to compile a minified css file which gets injected into the `wwwroot` folder of the WASM project.

So the `style.scss` would look something like this:

```
/* ======================= SCSS variables ======================= */

// theme colors
$primary: #00f000;
$secondary: #4c4c4c;
$success: #009000;
$info: #B6E600;
$danger: #f00000;

//layout 
$nav-sidebar-size: 14rem;
$nav-sidebar-size-collapsed: 3rem;
$topbar-size: 5rem;
// and other general variables...


@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

// Navigation
$nav-link-padding-y: .75rem;
$nav-link-color: $light;
$nav-link-font-size: 1rem;
// and other bootstrap variables


@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";


/* ======================= Custom CSS  ======================= */



html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: transparent;
}
// and so on...
```

The question is as follows:
If I am using css isolation (e.g. `MyCustomComponent.razor.css`), is it still possible to use the variables set in my general style? If so, how can it be done?

For example I would like to do the following:

**MyComponent.razor.css:**

```
.list-group active {
    color: $secondary;
    background-color: $dark;
}
```

which unfortunately does not seem to work.